# ActiveRecord not providing all database columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have created a migration which added a new column to one of our tables/models (`cloud_photo_url`). However the API is not producing the value when I try to render it out... I have also noticed that others are missing as well.

I couldn't figure out how I can get the json output to include the value from `cloud_photo_url`. To be clear, it is being persisted in the database, but for whatever reason the API is not returning the value. If I change or update other values (such as `first_name` or `last_name`) those changes are reflected in the json response.

db/schema:

```
     Column      |            Type             |                       Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id              | uuid                        | not null default shared_extensions.uuid_generate_v4()
 last_seen_at    | timestamp without time zone |
 auth_token      | character varying           |
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone | not null
 first_name      | character varying           |
 last_name       | character varying           |
 email           | character varying           |
 birthday        | date                        |
 provider_id     | character varying           |
 password_digest | character varying           |
 gender          | integer                     | default 0
 verified        | boolean                     | default false
 photo           | character varying           |
 provider        | integer                     | default 0
 cloud_photo_url | character varying           |
```

Ruby code:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
render json: @user
```

json output from the api endpoint:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": "8c29a48e-c2c2-4374-b8e6-f9d7c6970a9a",
        "auth_token": "WH4fveVNa1vANgD6LKbVJPL2",
        "provider": "guest",
        "provider_id": "111959522860722",
        "first_name": "miguel",
        "last_name": "martin",
        "email": "a@b.com",
        "verified": false,
        "gender": "unknown",
        "birthday": null,
        "photo": null,
        "pois": []
    }
}
```

## Edit 1:

• per the comments, `puts @user.to_json` does work with the full DB contents.

• yes, I am sure the values are being persisted to the DB. I am also sure the route is correct (as I indicated in my question, if I update other values which are displayed, they are similarly updated in the response).

• I would agree that there seems to be something interfering the `render :json`, but I am unable to figure out what. I looked for any `.rabl` files but nothing was found.

• using `render inline: @user.to_json, content_type: "application/json"` has me pretty close... the json is just slightly malformed (not encapsulated perfectly)... however I would prefer to fix this "the right way".

Any additional help on how to configure what could be affecting this route/render/model/controller would be helpful.

## Edit 2:

My model was asked for, here it is:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :updating_password

  mount_uploader :photo, UserPhotoUploader

  has_secure_password validations: false
  has_secure_token :auth_token

  enum gender: { unknown: 0, female: 1, male: 2 }, _prefix: true
  enum platform: { ios: 0, android: 1 }
  enum provider: { guest: 0, email: 1, facebook: 2 }, _prefix: true

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :enters, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pois, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :devices, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :outgoing_messages, class_name: 'MessageQueue', dependent: :destroy

  has_many :user_messages, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, through: :user_messages, source: :user

  validates_associated :devices

  validates :provider_id, presence: true, if: :provider_requires_id
  validates :first_name,  presence: true, unless: :provider_is_guest
  validates :last_name,   presence: true, unless: :provider_is_guest
  validates :email,
    presence: true,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
    format: { with: REGEX_EMAIL, message: 'Invalid email address' },
    unless: :provider_is_guest
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6, maximum: 128, message: 'must be greater than 5 characters' }, if: :setting_password?
  validates :provider_id, uniqueness: {
      scope: [:provider],
      message: 'Provider ID already exists'
  }, if: :provider_requires_id

  def gender=(g)
    g.try(:downcase!)

    gender = g.blank? ? 0 : g
    super(gender)
  end

  # IF not guest or email account then it requires a provider ID
  def provider_requires_id
    !['guest', 'email'].include?(self.provider)
  end

  def provider_is_guest
    provider_guest?
  end

  def setting_password?
    (self.provider_email? && new_record?) || updating_password
  end

  def name
    provider_guest? ? "Guest User" : "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def send_email_verification
    UserVerificationMailer.perform_later(current_tenant, self)
  end

  def send_password_reset
    UserPasswordResetMailer.perform_later(current_tenant, self)
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens if you try to access one of the hidden attributes with `@user.cloud_photo_url` before the render?

Comment: I'm thinking the conversion to json is probably overridden somewhere in the project.

Comment: @Qwertie empty string... But I am writing that from a train and my memory

Comment: It might actually be blank in the database. created_at would be a better one to try.

Comment: There are no methods in the User model that is filtering the json output?  If you just put the `@user` variable in a view like this `@user.attributes` does it show the `cloud_photo_url` ?

Comment: @BrianMorton double check the url you are access and method pointed to that route. add this before render ```puts @user.to_json``` and check console. what's the output? same?

Comment: Oh, another thing to check is the view thats creating the JSON. There is likely a .json.rabl file or similar with a whitelist of params to include.

Comment: Can you try `@user.attributes.to_json`?

Comment: @BrianMorton Do you use any Serializers?

Comment: Show the whole `models/user.rb` file.

Comment: I have updated the question to answer all of the relevant comments.

Comment: Could it be that the response is cached in some way? What are your exact steps to reproduce it?

Comment: @max there is no caching. as I said in the question, if I change one of the parameters that *IS* being returned, the value is updated in the response. This shows there is no caching, and that I am querying the correct route.

Comment: Thank you to @Gabbar who led me in the right direction. There was a gem for a serializer (`gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'`), so from the documentation on the gem I was able to figure out how to modify the `UserSerializer`. If @Gabbar wants to post an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BrianMorton Great to know that, i'll just give small brief by my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable),

Lets say

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
render json: @user
```

That means it will directly lookup `UserSerializer` to render `@user` object. 
the attributes which are defined in `UserSerializer` will be rendered as json ouput.

Other than this `active_model_serializers` has some options to customise json ouput for example: -

```
render json: @user, serializer: CustomUserSerializer, serializer_options: {}, status: 200
```

And in `custom_user_serializer.rb`

```
class CustomUserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :last_seen_at, 
             :auth_token,
             :created_at,
             :updated_at
             :...#so on
end
```